# "Unable to load DLL" when C#(UWP) call native c++ dll which calls another dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, uwp

I have a UWP c# app which calls a native C++ DLL named DLL2.dll and DLL2.dll calls another native C++ DLL named DLL1.dll. I put these two dll into a folder named library and the UWP project included this folder, selecting "copy always" in "Copy to output directory" and "content" in "Build action". In .cs file:(Dll2Init will call Dll1Init)

```
    [DllImport("library/Dll1.dll", EntryPoint = "DLL1Init", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern void DLL1Init();
    
    [DllImport("library/Dll2.dll", EntryPoint = "DLL2Init", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern void DLL2Init();//this function will call DLL1Init()

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        //DLL1Init();//will run well call DLL1Init before Dll2Init
        DLL2Init();
    }
```

When I run c#, it says "Unable to load DLL 'library/Dll2.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)". I have checked that Dll1.dll and Dll2.dll are already copied into App\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\library. And I do some tests:

1. I add Dll1Init() before DLL2Init(), it works well. These two functions work normally.
2. Don't add Dll1Init() before Dll2Init(). Copy Dll1.dll and Dll2.dll into App\bin\x64\Debug\AppX, and it works well too. It seems that it load dll from the same diretory(App\bin\x64\Debug\AppX) with app instead of the library.
3. I call Dll1Init() and it works well without DLL1.dll in App\bin\x64\Debug\AppX, meaning that it loads Dll1.dll from App\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\library.

From above, it seems that when app calls dll which doesn't call other third-party dll.The dll could be in any directory in case that it DllImport it. But if the c++ dll call another Dll, these DLLs only be put into the same directory with app. It's really strange. Do I miss something?
The sample is at [here](https://github.com/vincent1000/csharpUWP-cplusDLL/)

Comment: Are you saying `DLL1` has a dependency on `DLL2` and they work of you call `DLL1` first, but does not work if you call `DLL2` first ?

Comment: The error message indicates your Dll2 might failed to load Dll1. Maybe you need to post code of Dll1 and Dll2.

Comment: @TheGeneral DLL2 has a dependency on DLL1 and it works I call DLL1inti() first and it doesn't if I only call DLL2init()

Comment: @LouisGo I have already pasted the link : https://github.com/vincent1000/csharpUWP-cplusDLL/

Comment: May I know how you added dependency on dll1 in dll2? When I built the dll2 project, it failed. Could you please share the steps about it?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT select platform 'x64', build DLL1 first and dll1.dll and dll1.lib will create under csharpUWP\x64\Debug. Copy dll1.dll to csharpUWP\Dll2\x64\Debug and copy dll1.lib to csharpUWP\Dll2\ ,then build DLL2. It will create dll2.dll under csharpUWP\x64\Debug. Copy dll1.dll and dll2.dll into csharpUWP\library and build csharpUWP and run it.

Comment: You could try to move the dependent DLL(e.g. Dll1.dll) to the root folder of uwp project instead of library folder.

Comment: yes. I can do that and it proves to work well. But I want to manage all DLLs in a specific folder, when I publish, the folder can be integerated the package. So I wonder why Dll1.dll could not be in the folder. Is there any limitation for UWP to do like this?

Comment: You could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) to check the dll Search Order, it seems the project will search the dependent dll file in the root directory.